# column names with # in them rails and broken activemodel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a legacy table with (horrible) column names like LYEAR#2, LYEAR#3 ... LYEAR#9

I setup a model for it named Glamas

If I have:

```
accounts = Glamas.all
account_mains = accounts.collect(&:ACCOUNT_MAIN)
```

It breaks with this error:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:273: syntax error, unexpected kUNDEF, expecting ')'
                    undef :LYEAR#9?
                         ^
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:274: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:274:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:262:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:262:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:261:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:261:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:13:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:41:in `method_missing'
from (irb):31:in `to_proc'
from (irb):31:in `collect'
from (irb):31
from :0
```

Is this a problem with activemodel, or is it something that I can fix with something in my code?

This is rails 3 btw.

```
#glamas.rb
class Glamas < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "turnkey"
end
```

and...

```
#database.yml
turnkey:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: turnkey
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I am pulling the tables strait over from the legacy machine, I guess (If I absolutely have to) I could rename the columns when I pull them over, but the proess is already a huge pain and processor intensive.

Comment: How did you declare the table mapping?

Comment: updated question with this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use these tables with Active Record. AR defines instance methods for your classes which are named the same as the columns and in ruby `#` isn't allowed in method names (or any names for that matter as it's the comment character).

I'd suggest either creating views in the database with more sensible names or just renaming the columns.

Comment: Stupid legacy systems!! =)  Thanks for the info.

Comment: No problem. To go on a bit longer, you might find some workarounds with DataMapper or using read_attribute() in rails but to be honest you're just going to run in to other problems with the hash character. For example, any time one of them appears in a url it'll be interpreted as a fragment identifier (or anchor as people insist on calling them).