# replaced db/development.sqlite3 with db/Listings.sqlite3 (prepopulated database) getting ERROR : undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there Im a beginner to rails and what Im doing seems a common usecase to me yet, its funny it seems so hard to do in Rails and not many posts on the internet about the topic:

1. I created a new rails app. Since I had a legacy database that I wanted to include in my new rails app, I replaced the "development.sqlite3" with the legacy database "Listings.sqlite3"
2. Then I generated a model "business.rb" to match the table "Businesses" in my legacy db. Here is the code for it:

   ```
   class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

     establish_connection "Listings_development"

   end
   ```
3. Then I modified the "config/database.yml" file to include the following:

   ```yaml
   Listings_development:
     adapter: sqlite3
     database: db/Listings.sqlite3
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000

   Listings_test:
     adapter: sqlite3
     database: db/Listings.sqlite3
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000

   Listings_production:
     adapter: sqlite3
     database: db/Listings.sqlite3
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000
   ```
4. After that I generated the controller called "businesses_controller.rb" which has the following code:

   ```rb
   class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
     def show

     end

     def index
       @businesses = Business.all
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html #index.html.erb
       end
     end
   end
   ```
5. Finally I changed the "config/routes.rb" file to the following:

   ```rb
   Directory::Application.routes.draw do
     resources :businesses


     get "business/index"

     match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
   ```
6. Lastly I added a view file "index.html.erb:

   ```html
   <h1>Listing businesses</h1>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>Name:</th>
       <th>Phone Number:</th>
       <th>Address:</th>
     </tr>

   <% @businesses.each do |business| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= business.company_name %></td>
       <td><%= business.phone_number %></td>
       <td><%= business.address %></td>
   ```

I thought I was done, I had successfully managed to incorporate my legacy database and its data in my new rails app. But when I typed in "http://localhost:3000/businesses/" in my browser window. I get this error on the screen:

```
Showing /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/cmdLineWS/Directory/app/views/businesses/index.html.erb
where line #14 raised:

undefined method `company_name' for #<Business:0x00000104e1d0e8>
Extracted source (around line #14):

11: 
12: <% @businesses.each do |business| %>
13:   <tr>
14:     <td><%= business.company_name %></td>
15:     <td><%= business.phone_number %></td>
16:     <td><%= business.address %></td>
17:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', business %></td>
Rails.root: /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/cmdLineWS/Directory
```

Whats up with Rails?? Is it really that complex to include a legacy db? I thought the whole point of rails was rapid prototyping.

Here is a snapshot of my Listings.db file
[image]

Comment: As an aside, the "whole point of Rails" is building web applications, and in my opinion the words "rapid prototyping" and "legacy database" don't really belong in the same paragraph.

Comment: What is the structure of your Businesses table?

Comment: just added an image of my Listings.db which contains the Businesses table these are the columns: "Company Name", "Address", "Suite Number
", "City", "Province", "Phone Number", "Postal Code", "Fax Number", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Website"
Thanks

Comment: Update: I know that the database is being read because I can dump the contents of the database onto the browser window for debug purposes by adding the following line to the loop in the index.html.erb file:"<% @businesses.each do |business| %>
  
 <%=business.inspect %> <br> <br>
<% end %>"

Comment: Good, can you post the output of business.inspect :)? (I'm curious :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be caused by the fact the businesses' columns contains spaces and uppercase chars (e.g. I see "Company Name" in the screenshot instead of the wanted "company_name"). I don't know if rails support this kind of attribute names.

BTW is not a good practice have spaces and other strange characters in column names (in my humble opinion)

Comment: Yes I agree its bad practice. I will need to change that. But in the meanwhile I can see the database contents on the browser. So @businesses (and thus my model) can read all the data. But there is some mistake with the method itself. :(

Comment: You can see database content in the browser? BTW you could rename database columns to use better names like "company_name" and try again. You could use something like SQLite Database Browser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: Wait...you don't need to read/write DB content from the legacy application and with the rails application right? In that case rename the columns will break the legacy application...

Comment: Yes it was the mismatch between the column names in the model and the database table headers. Thanks. It works now :)

Comment: I'm glad you don't need to still run the legacy application *AND* the rails application because you probably would not be able to access a table with these column names :P (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663574/column-names-with-in-them-rails-and-broken-activemodel)

Comment: As the answer @Aldo'xoen'Giambelluca links to points out, another option—often the best one—is to create a view in your database with Rails-friendly column names. [Here's a presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/napcs/rails-and-legacy-databases-railsconf-2009) on dealing with legacy databases (relevant bits start on slide 19) and [here's SQLite's docs](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger) on making `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` work on views.